# Texture Painting - object is pink like it has no texture

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

I have a simple object, I UV unwrapped it, gave it a material and a texture but if I go to *Texture Paint* it still looks like it has no texture - I mean, it's pink - and Blender doesn't let me paint on it. It doesn't say anything, it just doesn't work.

If I don't add anything at first and click on Texture Paint then add an Alpha texture, Blender gives a material and a texture but the object is still pink and I still can't paint on it.

Any ideas why?

Comment: If object already has material and texture assigned to it and you'd like to use *them* instead of creating new ones what is proposed to do in Texture Painting tools, you can try to open its texture you'd like to paint on and click on its name. Blender should recognize availability of the paint slot and it will appear in painting tool box.

Comment: Please add a screen image of  your problem to your question.  Blender has some error message on screen. Some error messages in the console window which you can enable with ... Menu Window .. Toggle System Console. Sometimes Blender is the silent type.   Blender has never made me hot cocoa and read me a bedtime story.

Comment: Also make sure you have selected "Use shader nodes to render the material".

Answer (score 1):

For the texture in question make sure that
RGB to Intensity is [not] checked.

Good Setting.

[image]

Potentially Painful.

[image]

You might just delete your current textures and create fresh ones if you suspect errors have been introduced unintentionally.